# Node.js mongoose module failing on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, mongoose

Starting a couple days ago, our site **http://emaildelivery.herokuapp.com** displays an Application Error:

> "An error occurred in the application and your page could not be
>   served. Please try again in a few moments.
>
> If you are the application owner, check your logs for details."

**Our Heroku log shows:**

```
Jan 11 03:37:47 emaildelivery app/web.1: module.js:340 
Jan 11 03:37:47 emaildelivery app/web.1: throw err; 
Jan 11 03:37:47 emaildelivery app/web.1: ^ 
Jan 11 03:37:47 emaildelivery app/web.1: Error: Cannot find module './collection/shared' 
Jan 11 03:37:47 emaildelivery app/web.1: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15) 
Jan 11 03:37:47 emaildelivery app/web.1: at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25) 
Jan 11 03:37:47 emaildelivery app/web.1: at Module.require (module.js:364:17) 
Jan 11 03:37:47 emaildelivery app/web.1: at require (module.js:380:17) 
Jan 11 03:37:47 emaildelivery app/web.1: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection.js:14:14) 
Jan 11 03:37:47 emaildelivery app/web.1: at Module._compile (module.js:456:26) 
Jan 11 03:37:47 emaildelivery app/web.1: at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10) 
Jan 11 03:37:47 emaildelivery app/web.1: at Module.load (module.js:356:32) 
Jan 11 03:37:47 emaildelivery app/web.1: at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12) 
Jan 11 03:37:47 emaildelivery app/web.1: at Module.require (module.js:364:17) 
Jan 11 03:37:48 emaildelivery heroku/web.1: Process exited with status 8 
Jan 11 03:37:48 emaildelivery heroku/web.1: State changed from starting to crashed 
Jan 11 04:13:36 emaildelivery heroku/router: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/robots.txt host=emaildelivery.herokuapp.com fwd="66.249.73.12" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

The strange thing is, the site works fine locally on multiple dev machines. It's just on Heroku that it dies. We've tried upgrading/downgrading the node.js version and the mongoose module version, but can't seem to solve this problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try deleting `node_modules` folder and performing `npm install` and see the result? This is what Heroku is doing. Maybe you added node_modules to your repository, and it is being uploaded and making it unconsistent.

Comment: Mustafa is on the right track I think. Somehow you're getting a messed-up version of the mongodb module here /app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb. Definitely something is going wrong with npm and your node_modules folder.

Comment: @Mustafa - that worked!  Please add an Answer and I'll award it to you.

Comment: @Kane Good to hear, I added it is an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try deleting `node_modules` folder and performing `npm install` and see the result? This is what Heroku is doing. Maybe you added `node_modules` to your repository, and it is being uploaded and making it unconsistent.